# Static file collections - Logo navbar does not show up

Tags: django

I am trying to have an image (logo) on the navbar.

My project is called "`mysite-project`" (where `manage-py`is), it contains the app "`mysite`".

In order to upload my static file I did the following:

1) **mysite-project/mysite/settings.py**

I added:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')
]
```

2) Created folders `static` and added my logo.png in:

**mysite-project/static/mysite-project/logo.png**

3) **mysite-project/templates/base.html**

```
{% load staticfiles %}
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'home' %}">

        <img src="{% static 'mysite/logo.png' %}" height=30 width=30 class="d-inline-block alighn-top" />
        Code of Conduct
      </a>
</nav>
```

4) In **mysite-project/mysite/urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('users/', include('users.urls')),
    path('users/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**HOWEVER** the image does not show up. I think I have some issues in the **settings.py** for the folders but I cannot find where

Comment: Are you running the app behind a webserver? [You can configure the dev server to serve static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) but you should consider running your app behind a webserver when deployed that would serve your static files straight from disk (I would suggest nginx)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, but I adde `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in my `mysite-project/mysite/urls.py`

Comment: You say that you added the static file to "mysite-project/static/mysite-project/logo.png" this does not match the static file referenced in the img src "{% static 'mysite/logo.png' %}" `mysite` does not match `mysite-project`. Do you not see the 404s coming from the dev server logs?

Comment: The navbar loads but instead of the logo, there is image that is not rendered. Problem persists even when I do: `<img src="{% static 'mysite-project/static/mysite-project/logo.png' %}" height=30 width=30 class="d-inline-block alighn-top" />
`

Comment: If I run `python manage.py collectstatic` I get as error: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/static'
`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your STATICFILES_DIRS setting. If you join a path that has a leading slash then the result will "ignore" any preceding arguments and everything after will be relative to root

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static/')  # This will result in "/static/"
]


STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')  # This will result in "<BASE_DIR>/static/"
]
```

`STATIC_ROOT` is the directory that you want to serve files from and the directory that `collect_static` will populate with all your static files, `STATICFILES_DIRS` is where Django will collect the files from. `STATICFILES_DIRS` shouldn't contain `STATIC_ROOT`. The usual layout for a project is something like this

```
myproject/  # The root of your repo
    myproject/
        myapp/
            static/  # This is where you put app specific assets
                ...
        static/  # This is where you put your generic static assets. Add this to STATICFILES_DIRS
            ...
    static/  # This is STATIC_ROOT and where your files are served from after being collected
```

The default value for `STATICFILES_FINDERS` will look in `STATICFILES_DIRS` **and** every apps static directory. If you are using git, you should add the static folder at the root of your repo to .gitignore

Comment: Thanks, I changed it to `'static'` no `/static/`, but now I have the error: `?: (staticfiles.E002) The STATICFILES_DIRS setting should not contain the STATIC_ROOT setting.
`